# Error Alert message In Opencart Template

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, opencart

I am Working on Project on opencart project and its about to Complete.I am Having One Problem now.when ever user click on other Tab open. Java is Displaying a alert ERROR message.It is because internet speed is slow or Page is not properly loaded.Still i want to remove that Message is there any way i can remove it or fix it. Please help me. 
[Here is the Link](http://sdfabrics.com)

Comment: Please include all relevant materials here. Reduced examples of code, error msgs, etc.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Simpley override the alert by using

```
<script>window.alert = function() {};</script>
```

Comment: This is like eating painkillers when you should take some antibiotics instead. I.e. curing the symptoms instead of infection itself.

Comment: yes i know but i hv tried everything to remove this error alert and nothing found thats why i used this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To block this irritating alert coming on your store, just include below script in your website header.

```js
<script>
(function() {
    var new_alert = window.alert;                  
    window.alert = function(str) {  //str variable return content which is passed to be shown in alert
    str1 = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); //Removing line break from string 
    if (str1 !="error"){ //show alert only if content is not equal to 'error'
    new_alert(str); 
} 
else{
    // do nothing
}
   };
})();
</script>
```

**If you are wondering what it does:**
It just replaces default alert function of javascript and don't show alert when its content is 'error'.